# Custom template Logo and description in iPhone Application Templates

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, project-template, xcode-template

I am trying to create a custom "Application template".

I tried to learn, "How to create template?" from the sample templates of "Cocos2d iPhone Game development".

The problems that I am facing are as follows.

- Cocos2d custom application templates have logo - "create new project" screen. (**I don't know how to place the default logo of the Application template**: each template has different logo, like utility application, navigation based application, window based application etc.)
- Each application template has description at bottom in "create new project"
  (Like, navigation-based application will have description at the bottom.)
  My problem is **from where to put this description regarding the application template?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you locate the template in `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Project Templates` then Show Package Contents on the .xcodeproj file you will see it contains a TemplateIcon.icns. If you add/modify this file then it will appear in your project templates.

Also, with the description, again if you do the Show Package Contents on the .xcodeproj file you will see a file called TemplateInfo.plist. It contains some code that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>Description</key>
    <string>This is the description for the template</string>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: superb. having great knowledge. Superb.